# Same content different size jars file java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java

I have a problem with two jar files the same name.
**commons-lang3-3.0.jar** I've got with **298 kB** and **478 kB** size.

When run application with bigger file I've got **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError** that refer to that jar file.
With smaller jar file application works.

I've got investigation and

- unpack jars content and checked that got same size,
- compare content - the same(manifest file, class files, etc.).
- compare byte code class version of class from jar - the same 49(Java 5)
- compare binary jars and there is differences but I don't know where it came from

I don't have ideas of what was happened? Why same content doesn't work both cases?

**EDIT**

Thanks pikrut and Tobías for pointing me to solution. I've cleaned .m2 directory and run mvn clean install again.
Then I've got correct commons-lang3-3.0.jar 298 kB size.
I looked at wrong commons-lang3-3.0.jar in edit mode again. Looking for occurrence of some class name string and noticed that in bigger jar are duplicates of it. 
So I assume that wrong jar has duplicated stuff. Maven something broke.

Thanks all for help.

Comment: _Same content different size_, that's unlikely (but not impossible with compression), this is only the same file name. You should get a clean version of the jar, one of those is probably a bad one renamed. In your investigation, is it the same kind of project, package name, ... ?

Comment: If you are using maven , do a 'clean install' build.

Comment: As @AxelH pointed out, they are not the same library. Check for integrity, you can find the md5 or sha1 for commons-lang3-3.0 at: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.0/